# Deploy a ASP.NET website in AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have to deploy my .NET web application in AWS. I am very new to AWS and I have very little time to complete this task.

Please help me by providing me some steps to be followed or any tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really easy. This can be done via AWS Elastic BeanStalk. 
It very very simple and can be done in minutes.

You can follow the steps here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html

This should be helpful too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-N0z5K_WFI&t=606s

AWS Elastic BeanStalk is free but the EC2 instances running will incur charge. When setting up the application in Elastic BeanStalk console in AWS, choose single instance rather than load balanced/autoscaled etc. if it is not a production application.

Let me know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: I created an instance using EC2 . How can I publish my .net site in to this instance . Considering continuous deployment I would like to publish the site from my .net code using Jenkins . Is this possible ?